# Touchscreen support after update dropped

Tags: linux, arch-linux, touchscreen, input

I'm an ArchLinux user
I'm having an issue using evdev with my touchscreen (on Raspberry3 Board)
before upgrading the system all works regulary.After the upgarde the touchscreen doesn't recognize touch in the top side and doesn't send touch events.
Where can I start to understand the problem? I think is something related to Wayland/libinput/evdev

Comment: There is a dedicated support forum for ARM devices here: https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/

Comment: I dont think is related to archlinux.but I already post on that forum..no answer for the moment

Comment: The first thing to do then is to downgrade the packages between the time it didn't work and did.  Once you downgrade, if it works again then it is definitely software.

Comment: Already re-flashed the working sdcard image andò works with no problem...seems xorg seen the touchscreen as mouse...it lose touch event functionality totally

Comment: Since it is now proven to be a software issue I think you'd do better on the Arch Linux ARM forums.  Although, the answer you're looking for might also fix itself with further updates as they become available.